# How to put a break in a for loop from continuing to the line until user submits form (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an experiment where I have a set of images that I want to show in sequence and ask the user to answer what they think the image is depicting. In order to do this, I am using a for loop in Javascript in an HTML file that will loop the number of times of the number of images. I am trying to get the loop wait to continue to the next line of code until the user submits the form, and I'm not really sure how to do that.

I have tried using the While true loop, which contains a setTimeout function to check if the user submitted the form, in the parent for loop. I have also tried adding event handlers to check if the form was submitted, but the loop does not wait to continue to the next line like I would like it to.

```
var data = new FormData();
            var createform = document.getElementById('usrInpt');
            var imageNames = new Array("practiceImages/RiseFrame01.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame02.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame03.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame04.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame05.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame06.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame07.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame08.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame09.jpg","practiceImages/RiseFrame10.jpg") // This is the array of images
            function happyData() {
                    console.log("in happydata")
                    buttonPressed = true
                    //var newImageName = document.getElementById('imgName');
                    //newImageName.parentNode.removeChild(newImageName);
                    //var hiddenElementJS = document.getElementById('hiddenElement');
                    //hiddenElementJS.parentNode.removeChild(hiddenElementJS)
                    //submissionName.setAttribute("value", "")
            }
            for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                var buttonPressed = false;
                var hiddenElement = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenElement.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenElement.setAttribute("id", "hiddenElement");
                hiddenElement.setAttribute("name", "imageName");
                var currentImageStr = imageNames[i]
                var fields = currentImageStr.split('/')
                console.log(fields[1])
                hiddenElement.setAttribute("value", fields[1])
                createform.appendChild(hiddenElement)
                var y = document.getElementById("imageDisplay");
                var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                newImage.setAttribute("id", "imgName");
                newImage.setAttribute("src",imageNames[i]);
                newImage.setAttribute("width", "30%")
                newImage.setAttribute("height", "50%")
                newImage.setAttribute("max-width","30%");
                newImage.setAttribute("max-height","50%");
                y.appendChild(newImage);
                var Hisubmit = document.getElementById('submit');
                console.log(i)

                // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE IT TO PAUSE UNTIL THE USER SUBMITS THE FORM

                console.log(i)
            }
```

Using the code above, it should print out all 10 images on the webpage, including the text box for responses.

Comment: This may help -> function()* and yield -> https://mzl.la/30AsLrm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do ... while` and run the loop until user enter answer the question

something like this so you would disable form button until he enters the answer

```
do {
   // disable submit button
   // or make alert message to tell him to answer first
} while(userInput == '')
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm going for here. I'm trying to see when (and to wait for when) they submit the form so the loop can continue.

Comment: `do while` will stop your outer loop [for loop] until user enter the answer that what understand from you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a JavaScript for-loop, it will be impossible to have the `FORM` wait for `INPUT` as you describe as you render the `DOM`.

I believe your approach needs to be modified, so that you create a state object that manages the list of images to rate, and the current image being rated. After the user `SUBMITs` the `FORM`, the current image would be incremented and the actions would continue until the end.

If you truly want to pause a JavaScript for-loop, I would suggest using the **prompt** method:

```
for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
  //...
  var input = prompt("What do you think of image " + i + "?", "10");
  //...
}
```

Comment: I agree with you now that I see your code that my method could be improved. I am having a different issue that is kind of related to this though. When the prompt is entered, I have to open a new page to do the PHP processing of the information. Because of this, the interaction tab is out of focus which makes chrome return nothing in each prompt as long as focus is not on the window. Any thoughts on how to get around this?